# Prove that the Wronskian of a fundamental set of solutions is always non-zero?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation, fundamental-solution, wronskian

Given a set of fundamental solutions to an nth order linear homogeneous differential equation $y_1, y_2, y_3, ..., y_n$, can we prove that the Wronskian of this set is **always** non-zero for **any** value of x on the interval for which the solution set is defined?

I haven't been able to find a set of fundamental solutions whose Wronskian is zero for at least one value of x, and I'm not sure how to prove it. Conversely, I haven't been able to find a set of solutions that do not form a fundamental set, whose Wronskian is always non-zero.

As an example, if we look at the fundamental set $e^x, xe^x, x^2e^x$, it has a Wronskian of $2e^{3x}$. No value of x can make this Wronskian equal to zero. Conversely, the non-fundamental set $e^x, x^2e^x$ has a Wronskian $2xe^{2x}$, which can made zero using a substitution of x=0. I want to find out if this is true for all fundamental and non fundamental sets.

Any tips/proofs available?

This page mentions "Thereom 3" which seems like what I want, but without a proof. [The Wronskian and the term "fundamental set of solutions"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2359046/the-wronskian-and-the-term-fundamental-set-of-solutions)

Comment: By definition, no. If the Wronskian is zero then the set of solutions is not linearly independent, and is therefore not a fundamental set of solutions.

Comment: I specified that the Wronskian must always be non-zero.

Comment: Right. So if the Wronskian being zero would mean the set of solutions is not fundamental, then...? (hint: contrapositive)

Comment: You are not understanding. The set of solutions are linearly dependent if the Wronskian is 0 for all values of x, where it is therefore quite obviously not a fundamental set. I am trying to prove that if the Wronskian is non-zero for all values of x, then it forms a fundamental set (or conversely, if it is zero for at least one value of x, it cannot form a fundamental set).  This goes deeper than the definition of Wronskian. If you have a proof you could point me towards that would be appreciated

Comment: I'm still really not sure what you want, a set of solutions is fundamental where its Wronskian is nonzero and it's not fundamental where its Wronskian is zero. I'm not sure how this gets any more clear-cut.

Comment: If we take, for example, the non-fundamental set $e^x, x^2e^x$, it has a Wronskian of $2xe^{2x} $ i.e. it is nonzero but not *always* non-zero (is zero at $x=0$). On the other hand, the fundamental set $e^x, xe^x, x^2e^x$ has Wronskian $2e^{3x} $, which is *always* non-zero (no value of x will make it 0). Is this always the case with all fundamental/non-fundamental solutions? If so, can we prove it?

Comment: @StephenDonovan I have added the example to the body of my question as well